# Jquery script with comments ID's

Tags: jquery

My html looks like this (simplified)

```
$args = array(...);
    
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments       = $comments_query->query( $args );  
    
foreach ($comments as $comment) { 

    <a class="respond-to-messages" href="#<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>">Reply to message</a>
    
        <div id="comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" class="comment-respond-form post-id-<?php echo $comment->comment_post_ID; ?>">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <form id="custom_comments-form" action="" method="post">
                        
                        //form fields
                        
                        <button class="uk-button" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div> 

}
```

[image]

My jquery

```
jQuery(function ($) {   
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".comment-respond-form").hide();
        $(".respond-to-messages").show();

        $('.respond-to-messages').on('click',function(){            
            $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Reply to message' ? 'Hide form' : 'Reply to message');          
            
            $(".comment-respond-form").slideToggle(function(){
                if($('.comment-respond-form').height() > 0) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("comment-respond-form").offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Because we're in a loop with multiple comments, `.comment-respond-form` should actually be `comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>`
But the jquery script is added outside the loop (in the footer and inside a .js file).

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: (we're almost there)

I created an extra button to expand/collapse all forms

```
<button class="collapse-forms" href="#">Collapse All</button>

$('.collapse-forms').on('click',function(){         
            $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Collapse All' ? 'Expand All' : 'Collapse All');             
            
            $(".comment-respond-form").slideToggle(function(){
                
                
            });
        });
```

But what I noticed is the following

[image]

How to modify my code so that all forms will open/close regardless whether they were closed or open before?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but isn't what you're trying to do exactly what WP's comment-reply.js already does?

Comment: The plugin I use, uses a custom form. Along with `wp_nonce_field` and other extra `input hidden` fields, so I tend to change as little as possible. But I'll take your advice to heart and try to look more into a custom comment form and the reply link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your javascript console for errors.

You can't use $ in WordPress.  Replace it with jQuery everywhere but jQuery(function ($).

Comment: I checked on Chrome and I don't have any errors in my console.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking how to call `.slideToggle()` *only* on the commenting form specific to each comment. Is that correct?

If so, you can use the [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function in jQuery to get the element immediately following the link that was clicked.

```
var $reply_form = $(this).next();
$reply_form.slideToggle(function(){
    if($reply_form.height() > 0) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $reply_form.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

This requires that your HTML code look exactly as you describe it, with the `.comment-respond-form` immediately following `.respond-to-messages`.

Comment: Thank you, you answer helps. :) There one more thing in which I've updated my first post.

Comment: Try using `slideUp` and `slideDown` instead of `slideToggle`.

Comment: Could you make an example on how to use both slideDown/Up? I'm kind of new to Jquery.

Comment: Found a way. :) Although I ran into another issue, I'll create a different question for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the id attribute in anchor tag please see this working code with jQuery..

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {

<a class="respond-to-messages" id="<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" href="#<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>">Reply to message</a>

    <div id="comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" class="comment-respond-form post-id-<?php echo $comment->comment_post_ID; ?>">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <form id="custom_comments-form" action="" method="post">

                    //form fields

                    <button class="uk-button" type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div> 
} 


jQuery('.respond-to-messages').click(function(){ 

  jQuery(".comment-respond-form").hide();

  var current_id = this.id;

  jQuery('#comment-'+current_id).slideDown();

});
```

I hope this will help you

Please see example of your code https://jsfiddle.net/Ni3singhchouhan/q08vvq3v/